# pandas: merge/combine/update two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes

```
   id  nr   lval
0   1  one     1
1   2  two     2
2   3  one     3

   id  nr  rval
4   1  one     4
5   2  one     5
6   3  one     6
```

I need merge or combine these two dataframes and use column 'id' as a key.
By collision (column 'nr') take the column from first dataframe.
Result should looks like this:

```
   id  nr   lval  rval
0   1  one     1     4
1   2  two     2     5
2   3  one     3     6
```

Answer (score 0):

As the shapes of the dfs are the same you can call [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first), the lhs df values supercede the rhs df hence you keep the nr column values:

```
In [3]:

df.combine_first(df1)
Out[3]:
   id  lval   nr  rval
0   1     1  one     4
1   2     2  two     5
2   3     3  one     6
```

Comment: In your df examples the id looks like a column, if it's the index it should still work fine